# How to Create a Zend_Navigation Dummy Node - Zend Framework 1.11.4

Tags: zend-framework, zend-navigation

i'm trying to create a node in the Zend_Navigation tree that is just used for organizing the links within it.  therefore it would NOT require an anchor tag when rendered and not show up in the breadcrumb.  anyone know how to make this happen?

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what your're after. I assume that you use `navigation.xml` in `application/config` folder to organize your navigation. Then you could provide a dummy navigation element and disable it using css:

```
<all>
    <label>Home</label>
    <resource>default:Home</resource>
    <module>default</module>
    <class>dummy</class>
</all>
```

Comment: How would you disable the href element using css?  Is there any way to render that node in the navigation without the anchor tag?

Comment: what do you want to display? with css and js you could do quite everything with the element, e.g. change the tag..